# Ant dependencies build failed with checksum error

Tags: java, ant

I am using JAVA 11.0.11

I have installed ant on my Linux desktop.
Then to install optional dependencies i run following command which is on the documentation.
`ant -f fetch.xml -Ddest=system`
After running , I received following error.

```
-setup-temp-cache:

-fetch-netrexx:
      [ftp] getting files
      [ftp] 0 files retrieved

-fetch-netrexx-no-commons-net:

netrexx:
 [checksum] Could not find file /root/.ant/tempcache/NetRexx.zip to generate checksum for.

BUILD FAILED
/usr/local/apache-ant/fetch.xml:368: Could not find file /root/.ant/tempcache/NetRexx.zip to generate checksum for.

Total time: 22 seconds
```